# Output was lost in linux terminal. How do I restore?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I was executing the script and sequentially outputting the result of the execution to the command line. Since there was too much data, the output was lost, and now I only have the last part of it on the screen. Is it possible to get the whole output somehow?

Comment: You needed to use the tee command.

Comment: It depends on the terminal application you are using. Some can be configured to hold a certain amount of the output so that you can scroll back to see it. However, this is a question about terminal configuration and should be asked at [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once the output in a terminal window is gone, you can't get it back. Therefore it's advised, either to work with a terminal that can contain more than just one screen, or to forward your output to an output file, which you can analyse afterwards.